# Algorithm: Finding the Mode with Imperfect Values

Tags: algorithm, average, mode

I want to find the mode of a dataset where the numbers are close, but not exact. For example let's say I have the following array:

[0.00, 100.12, 101.00, 99.75, 97.5, 102.4, 36.34, 103.11, 100.20, 75.0]

I want to get a number around 100 out of this array. I could just take the average, but I don't want 0.00, 36.34 and 75.00 spoil the rest of the numbers.

Another way to phrase this is I want the average of the values, excluding the ones that aren't close to the others.

Thanks!

Comment: What you are describing is quite different from "mode" (=the value that occurs most frequently), so you may want to remove the tag and change the title.

Comment: You may be interested in reading about RANSAC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC

Answer (score 1):

How about using the **median** instead of the mean?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median

Or use a "trimmed mean". Drop the top 10% and bottom 10% of values, compute the mean only on the remainder. It is supposedly more stable.

Comment: But the median of [0, 10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000] is 200.

Comment: Yes, so what if? Add two more 1000 observations and it will be 1000. the median has pretty good semantics, in particular on real data.

Comment: A histogram doesn't have this problem, and it may also be faster.

Comment: A histogram may also just fail to produce sensible results at all, because the bin size has been badly chosen. Note that trimmed mean, median and similar approaches are closely related to a "flexible bin size histogram".

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution would be to compute a histogram and find its maximum. You may want to play with the bin size.

Comment: Make that an **and you will need to play with the bin size**. This is critical for the histogram to work reasonably, so you might need multiple tries with different bin sizes to get a sensible result. In the end, you will also want to refine it within the bin.